# VBA Word "for each" loop goes infinite while looking at revisions collection

Tags: vba, ms-word

My code fills the list of authors of the revisions in a Word document:

```
Private Sub Get_Revisions_Authors()
    Dim r As Revision
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Authors As New Collection
    For Each r In doc.content.Revisions
        Authors.Add r.Author, r.Author
    Next r
```

The code had been working fine until it got stuck on one new document. In that case the loop "for - each" just goes infinitely picking some group of five revisions one-by-one again and again.
Rewriting the code into something like this solves the problem:

```
Private Sub Get_Revisions_Authors()
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Authors As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To doc.content.Revisions.Count
        Authors.Add doc.content.Revisions(i).Author, doc.content.Revisions(i).Author
    Next i
```

Slightly rewritten code to remove "On Error Resume Next" line, but still going infinite selecting revisions without any error:

```
Private Sub Get_Revisions_Authors()
Dim r As Revision
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
Dim bAdd As Boolean
Dim i As Long
    For Each r In doc.content.Revisions
        bAdd = True
        For i = 1 To Authors.Count
            If r.Author = Authors(i) Then
                bAdd = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If bAdd Then
            Authors.Add r.Author, r.Author
        End If
    Next r
```

But maybe someone knows, how to find out what the problem is with the first version of code?

Comment: Remove ```On Error Resume Next``` and see if an error pops up.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Before and after the loop in your second version add `Debug.Print doc.content.Revisions.Count`. Perhaps that will help you understand.

Comment: @Warcupine 'On Error Resume Next' is used to add authors to Authors collection without checking if there already exists such author, without this line the error of adding occurs. After removing this line and rewriting  the code to include "if not author in Authors then add" checkup, the loop selecting revisions just goes infinite without any error.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt adding Debug.Print doc.content.Revisions.Count before and after the loop just prints the same number... as it should, I think

Comment: @Torcian I highly recommend to check how to use `On Error Resume Next` in combination with `On Error Goto 0` properly. As you did it hides all error message in the entire procedure (not only the ones you are expecting from duplicate addings). Check out the link about error handling. As the code is now you cannot see if there are more errors than the expected ones.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for the suggestion, but I didn't hide any error message. After removing 'On Error Resume Next' line from the original code there actually was error message caused by adding duplicate author into Authors collection. So what I did is I rewrote code to avoid only that error and not to hide all errors of any type. Or maybe I can't still understand what is your suggestion about ((